# Visual Studio 2010 Load Test User Review?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, load-testing

I've been searching different Load Testing Tools for .NET applications. And came accross these tools;

- HP Loadrunner
- Silk Performer
- IBM RPT
- Visual Studio Load Test

Visual Studio Load Test meets all the requirements, as development tool used for .NET application is also Visual Studio.

I want **user review for Visual Studio Load Test** with examples/case studies or white papers.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your query in micorosoft user experience blogs: http://blogs.microsoft.nl/blogs/ux/